# Getting the sum of multiple array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the sum these `2 arrays` in JS or jquery. I also want to check if `b` exists or not empty. Here's my code:

```js
$('select[name=changer]').change(function() {
  var one = $(this).val();
  if (one == 'one') {
    alert('One');
  } else {
    var all_grade1 = $('select[name=grade\\[\\]]').val() || [];
    var all_grade2 = $('select[name=has_grade\\[\\]]').val() || [];
    var alls = all_grade1.concat(all_grade2);

    var yes = alls.reduce(getSum, 0);
    alert(yes);
  }

});

function getSum(total, value) {
  return total + parseInt(value, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="changer">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
</select>
<hr />
<select name="grade[]">
  <option value="1">Grade1</option>
  <option value="2">Grade2</option>
  <option value="3">Grade3</option>
</select>
<select name="grade[]">
  <option value="2">Grade2</option>
  <option value="4">Grade4</option>
  <option value="6">Grade6</option>
</select>
<select name="has_grade[]">
  <option value="1">HasGrade1</option>
  <option value="2">HasGrade2</option>
  <option value="3">HasGrade3</option>
</select>
```

I have research about this, but nothing seems to be match with my problem. Any suggestions/answers?

Comment: show the values of your two arrays and what output you are expecting based on those two array

Comment: Do you want to get the sum of lengths of both array or its values?

Comment: If `alls` was an array of numbers your code should work.I doubt that jquery gets an array directly with `val()`, you probably have either arrays with strings or worse a comma delimited string.Just console.log your values and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the DOM for all the relevant `<select>` elements

```
$('select[name=grade\\[\\]], select[name=has_grade\\[\\]]')
```

Iterate over them and get the value of the selected options as numbers

```
.get().map(function(select) {
    return parseInt(select.value, 10)
})
```

and sum them up

```
.reduce(getSum, 0)
```

All together this would look something like this:

```
$('select[name=changer]').change(function() {
  var one = $(this).val();

  if (one == 'one') {
    console.log('One');
  } else {
    var selects = $('select[name=grade\\[\\]], select[name=has_grade\\[\\]]');
    var yes = selects.get()                    // get the matched DOM nodes as an array
                      .map(function(select) {  // get the values (as numbers) of the selected options
                        return parseInt(select.value, 10);
                      })
                      .reduce(getSum, 0);      // sum the selected options

    console.log(yes);
  }
});
```

```js
$('select[name=changer]').change(function() {
  var one = $(this).val();

  if (one == 'one') {
    console.log('One');
  } else {
    var selects = $('select[name=grade\\[\\]], select[name=has_grade\\[\\]]');
    var yes = selects.get()                    // get the matched DOM nodes as an array
                      .map(function(select) {  // get the values (as numbers) of the selected options
                        return parseInt(select.value, 10);
                      })
                      .reduce(getSum, 0);      // sum the selected options

    console.log(yes);
  }
});

function getSum(total, value) {
  return total + parseInt(value, 10); // or parseFloat() depending on the value
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="changer">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
</select>
<hr />
<select name="grade[]">
  <option value="1">Grade1</option>
  <option value="2">Grade2</option>
  <option value="3">Grade3</option>
</select>

<select name="grade[]">
  <option value="2">Grade2</option>
  <option value="4">Grade4</option>
  <option value="6">Grade6</option>
</select>
<select name="has_grade[]">
  <option value="1">HasGrade1</option>
  <option value="2">HasGrade2</option>
  <option value="3">HasGrade3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it returns an error: `TypeError: alls.reduce is not a function`

Comment: @Jonjie In this snippet? If so, what browser do you use? [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Browser_compatibility) is available since IE9. If it is in your own code, than please show it (jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com, pastebin.com, ...)

Comment: Im using `firefox`. Have you tried **2** `exam[]` and/or **2** `has_exam[]`?

Comment: Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonjie0317/vuhczocL/25/)

Comment: Looks nice, I'll do it later sir.